# Deleting title from all graphs and charts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I wrote a very simple code to delete all titles from graphs. It works sometimes, but some other times nothing happens.

```
    Sub changeformatting()

For Each Sht In Application.Worksheets
    For Each cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        cht.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(6)
        cht.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(9)
        cht.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
        cht.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "arial"
        cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange = Delete


 On Error Resume Next
 
    Next cht
Next Sht

End Sub
```

I have workbooks with 20-30 graphs, and I would like to automise all the abovementioned stuff. When I create a sample file, with two graphs it works fine, on my big file, it gives an error if all graphs doesn't have a title.

The error code I get is "the object has no title".

Any idea how to fix this? I tried adding on error resume next, but doesnt seem to help.

When I debugg it obviously gives error for the delete row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the chart title, instead of deleting the The `TextFrame2`, delete the actual title. Also the delete method will fail if there is no title present.

Check if the chart has title and then delete it. For example try this.

```
If cht.Chart.Hastitle then cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Much apprecieated